# SQL: Default value of a column to be addition of two columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns like net and vat, I wanted to add a new column to the table called total, which should be by default the addition of net + vat... I am using Postgres as the database, is it possible to do what I expect?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Potsgres 12 or later, you can add a generated column:

```
alter table the_table
   add total numeric generated always as (net + vat) stored;
```

[Complete example online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=62a3e05dda4b5a2f82ba7cc97087a1ff)

Another solution for such a simple derived attribute is to create a view:

```
create view the_table_with_total
as
select <other columns>, net + vat as total
from the_table;
```